# iterating over an array of semi-unique objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

say you have an array of objects as shown at the bottom, how would you go about iterating over this array to get the results of every previous game played.
I basically got turned around when trying to iterate over values that didnt exist

```
the result im looking for would be an array looking something like this 
newArr: [
    {
        "id": 1,
        team: 'rockets',
        record:{
             first: 'win',
             second: 'loss',
             thrid: 'loss'
             }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        team: 'raptors',
        record:{
             first: 'loss',
             }
    },
     ...
     ...

]
```

```
gamesPlayed: [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "team": "rockets",
        prevScore: [{
            value: {results: 'win'},
            prevScore: [{
                value: {results: 'loss'},
                prevScore: [{
                    value: {results: 'loss'},
                    prevScore: []
                }]
            }]
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "team": "raptors",
        prevScore: [{
            value: {results: 'loss'},
            prevScore: []
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "team": "hornets",
        prevScore: [{
            value: {results: 'win'},
            prevScore: [{
                value: {results: 'win'},
                prevScore: []
            }]
        }]
    },
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iterating over the teams map-function is used.
Getting the id and the team for the object from collectResults is simple. For getting the record there is a function with parameter level which indicates the how maniest result will be the next evaluated for this team.
This function delievers an empty object if prevScore is an empty array else it will extract the first result in a new object. Then the function is called recursivly with level + 1 for the left results. The result-object from the actual game plus the result-object from the previous games will be added together with assign and returned.
 The corresponding object entity-name (first, second, ...) for the record can be extracted with array LEVELS and level. So you could extend it as much as you want it.

```js
function collectResults(gamesPlayed) {
    let res = gamesPlayed.map( teamPlay => {
        let result = {
            id: teamPlay.id,
            team: teamPlay.team,
            record: getResults(teamPlay.prevScore, 0)
        }
        return result;
    });
    return res;
}

function getResults(prevScore, level) {
    const LEVELS = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth'];
    if ( !prevScore.length ) 
        return {};
    else {
        let result= {};
        result[ LEVELS[level] ] = prevScore[0].value.results;
        let resultsPrevious = getResults(prevScore[0].prevScore, ++level);
   
        return Object.assign(result, resultsPrevious);
    }
}

let gamesPlayed = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "team": "rockets",
        prevScore: [{
            value: {results: 'win'},
            prevScore: [{
                value: {results: 'loss'},
                prevScore: [{
                    value: {results: 'loss'},
                    prevScore: []
                }]
            }]
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "team": "raptors",
        prevScore: [{
            value: {results: 'loss'},
            prevScore: []
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "team": "hornets",
        prevScore: [{
            value: {results: 'win'},
            prevScore: [{
                value: {results: 'win'},
                prevScore: []
            }]
        }]
    }
];

console.log( collectResults(gamesPlayed) );
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit messy. But it works for the input

```js
var data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "team": "rockets",
    prevScore: [{
      value: {
        results: 'win'
      },
      prevScore: [{
        value: {
          results: 'loss'
        },
        prevScore: [{
          value: {
            results: 'loss'
          },
          prevScore: []
        }]
      }]
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "team": "raptors",
    prevScore: [{
      value: {
        results: 'loss'
      },
      prevScore: []
    }]
  }

];

var result = [];
var numbers = {
  1: "first",
  2: "second",
  3: "third",
  4: "fourth"
};

for (obj of data) {
  var index = 1;
  var oneGameResult = {
    "id": obj.id,
    "team": obj.team
  }
  var oneGameObj = {};
  buildResult(obj.prevScore, oneGameObj, index);

  oneGameResult["record"] = oneGameObj;
  result.push(oneGameResult);
}

console.log("result", result);

function buildResult(obj, oneGameObj, index) {

  var a = numbers[index];
  if (obj[0].prevScore && obj[0].prevScore.length > 0) {
    oneGameObj[a]=obj[0].value.results;
      
    index++;
    buildResult(obj[0].prevScore, oneGameObj, index);
  } else if (index == 1) {
    oneGameObj[a]=obj[0].value.results;
  }
}
```

Comment: Record should be only 1 object with entities first, second, third and not an array of objects (look at the OP wishes).